# How to use Patch method in minimal api application?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to use patch method in my minimal api application this is my code :

Car class

```
public class Car
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "producent")]
    public Producent Producent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "yearCreated")]
    public int YearCreated { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "engine")]
    public Engine Engine { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        Id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        YearCreated = DateTime.Now.Year - Age;
    }
}
```

ICarService:

```
public interface ICarService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetAll();
    Task<Car> GetById(string id,string partitionKey);
    Task Create(Car car);
    Task<bool> Update(Car car);
    Task<Car> UpdatePatchAsync(string id, string partitionKey,List<PatchOperation> patchOperations);

    Task<bool> Delete(string id,string partitionKey);
}
```

patch method in service

```
public async Task<Car> UpdatePatchAsync(string id, string partitionKey, List<PatchOperation> patchOperations)
    {
        var result = await _container.PatchItemAsync<Car>(id, new PartitionKey(partitionKey),
            patchOperations:patchOperations );

        return result;
    }
```

my requests:

```
    [HttpPatch]
    public static async Task<IResult> Patch(ICarService service,string id,string partitionKey, 
        [FromBody]List<PatchOperation> operations)

    {
        var updatedCar = await service.UpdatePatchAsync(id,partitionKey,operations);

        if (updatedCar == null)
        {
            return Results.NotFound();
        }
        return Results.Ok(updatedCar);
    }

app.MapMethods("/cars/patch/{id}/{partitionKey}", new string[] { "PATCH" }, CarRequests.Patch);
```

I use cosmosDb database and when i code like this:

```
{
"op": "replace",
"path": "age",
"value": 22
```

}

i get the error

```
System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.PatchOperation'. Path: $[0] | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 3.
```

---> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.PatchOperation'.

Comment: What is there in operations

Comment: I want to post operations in postman

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `[FromBody]List<PatchOperation> operations`.

This is making ASP.NET attempt to deserialize a JSON raw string into `PatchOperation`, which when we look at our source code, has no parameterless constructor: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Patch/PatchOperation.cs, it is an abstract class.

The way it is meant to be used is through `PatchOperation.XXXX`, like `PatchOperation.Add`, you cannot use it to deserialize into it. You could have your own `MyPatchOperation<Car>` that has the exposed properties for deserialization, and then simply have a method in that class that based on which properties are populated, calls `PatchOperation<Car>.Add` (or whatever operation).

Not the full code but:

```
public class MyPatchOperation
{
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "op")]
public string Operation { get; set; }
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "path")]
public string Path { get; set; }
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
public string Value { get; set; }

public PatchOperation<Car> ToPatchOperation()
{
  switch (this.Operation)
  {
      case "replace":
         return PatchOperation<Car>.Replace(this.Path, this.Value);
      /* other operations */
  }
}
}
```